# What I must do to activate my site by Magento

Tags: websites

When I go to my site it shows "Sorry, your Website is in work". My question is how I can do that this is not there and all can see my site.

Comment: Please stop posting the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You will find a maintenance.flag file in your root directory. Delete it.